# WARNING: no logs are available with the 'local' log driver when using different docker context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy few containers in my development environment. In order to do that, I switch docker context and then execute my docker-compose stack. I specify in my docker compose file the local driver this way:

```
    logging:
      driver: local
      options:
        max-size: '2m'
        max-file: '10'
```

Containers output is:
 `WARNING: no logs are available with the 'local' log driver`

Has this ever happened to you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to my docker-compose version. 1.25 does not work with context good apparently. Even if I was switching contexts, docker-compose was just starting the containers on my machine, not on the remote context. I updated the version to 1.29 and then It started working just fine.